# Como fazer relacionamento entre 5 tabelas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas: `conteúdo`, `aulas`, `curso`, `turma`, `grupo_User` aonde a lógica será a seguinte:

1. Um conteúdo pode pertencer a diversas aulas, como uma aula pode ter  diversos conteúdos
2. Uma aula pode pertencer a diversos cursos, assim como um curso pode ter diversas aulas.
3. Um curso pode pertencer a várias turmas, assim como uma turma pode ter diversos cursos para se matricular.
4. Um grupo de usuários pode estar vinculado a diversas turmas, assim como uma turma pode receber diversos grupos de usuários diferente.

Se eu estiver certo, esses relacionamentos são todos **N:N**, sei também que é necessário uma tabela a mais para realizar a ligação entre as tabelas.

Abaixo deixarei a estrutura das tabelas:

**Conteudo:**

```
CREATE TABLE conteudo (
    id INT(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    autor VARCHAR(50),
    conteudo MEDIUMTEXT,
    data_criacao DATETIME,
    ultima_edicao VARCHAR(50),
    data_edicao DATETIME
);
```

**Aulas:**

```
CREATE TABLE aulas (
    id INT(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    autor VARCHAR(50),
    nome VARCHAR(50),
    data_criacao DATETIME,
    ultima_edicao VARCHAR(50),
    data_edicao DATETIME
);
```

**Curso:**

```
CREATE TABLE curso (
    id INT(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    autor VARCHAR(50),
    nome VARCHAR(50),
    data_criacao DATETIME,
    ultima_edicao VARCHAR(50),
    data_edicao DATETIME
)
```

**Turmas:**

```
CREATE TABLE turmas(
    id INT(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    autor VARCHAR(50),
    nome VARCHAR(50),
    data_criacao DATETIME,
    ultima_edicao VARCHAR(50),
    data_edicao DATETIME
)
```

**Grupo_User:**

```
CREATE TABLE grupo_User(
    id INT(12) PRIMARY KEY,   
    nome_Grupo VARCHAR(50),
    id_Users INT(20)
)
```

Até consegui ligar o conteúdo às aulas usando a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE aula_has_conteudo (
    idAula INT(12),
    idConteudo INT(12),
    CONSTRAINT PK_aulas_has_conteudo PRIMARY KEY (idAula, idConteudo),
    CONSTRAINT FK_aulas_has_conteudo_aula FOREIGN KEY (idAula) REFERENCES aulas (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_aulas_has_conteudo_conteudo FOREIGN KEY (idConteudo) REFERENCES conteudo (id)
);
```

Usando o seguinte `SELECT` consigo trazer os dados pretendidos:

```
SELECT  a.autor as autorAula, c.conteudo as conteudo FROM aulas a INNER JOIN aula_has_conteudo h ON a.id = h.idAula 
INNER JOIN conteudo c ON c.id = h.idConteudo
```

E consegui ligar as `aulas` com os `cursos` usando a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE curso_has_aula (
    idCurso INT(12),
    idAula INT(12),
    CONSTRAINT PK_curso_has_aula PRIMARY KEY (idCurso, idAula),
    CONSTRAINT FK_curso_has_aula_Curso FOREIGN KEY (idCurso) REFERENCES curso (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_curso_has_aula_Aula FOREIGN KEY (idAula) REFERENCES aulas (id)
)
```

Mas não consigo realizar a ligação entre as outras tabelas.

**Como posso relacionar todas essas tabelas sabendo os requisitos citados acima?**

Após relacionadas, como posso fazer um `select` para obter dados das cinco tabelas?

Comment: quais as outras tabelas de ligação? do tipo "aula_has_curso" por exemplo?

Comment: editei a pergunta @RicardoPontual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você seguir fazendo os joins com as demais tabelas, vai ficar grande mas é só ir adicionando as demais tabelas:

```
SELECT a.autor as autorAula, c.conteudo as conteudo 
  FROM aulas a 
 INNER JOIN aula_has_conteudo h ON a.id = h.idAula 
 INNER JOIN conteudo c ON c.id = h.idConteudo
 INNER JOIN curso_has_aula cha on a.id = cha.idAula
 INNER JOIN curso cr on cr.id = cha.idCurso
 -- e assim por diante
```

Comment: Ricardo, então está certo eu ir realizando os relacionamentos com uma tabela a mais? Por exemplo, relacionar o `curso` com a `turma` eu criaria a tabela `turma_has_curso` e seguiria o mesmo raciocínio no select?

Comment: Sim, se a relação for `n: n`, se for `1: n`, a tabela "n" pode receber uma chave estrangeira e não precisaria criar outra tabela

Comment: Muito bom, então eu estava seguindo o raciocínio correto, só queria ter certeza de que estava certo. Em relação ao `select`, obrigado pela orientação.

Comment: Trnaquilo, disponha :)